# Start multiple rq worker processes easily ― Horizontal scaling

Tags: python, vps, worker, horizontal-scaling

How can I create a large number of [rq](https://python-rq.org) worker processes in a VPS easily?

Right now I'm manually opening a terminal and running `python3 worker.py` in it, and then repeating this until I get a satisfying number of worker instances running. I know this is not a scalable solution, so how can I do it automatically and easily. It'd be nice if there were some tool which facilitates this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It seemed like a pretty good solution.

The relevant `supervisord.conf` file looks like this.

```
[supervisord]

[program:worker]
command=python worker.py
process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
numprocs=20
directory=.
stopsignal=TERM
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

After putting this file in the same directory as of the RQ worker script `worker.py`, just running the following command will spawn up 20 instances of the RQ worker. The number of workers can be specified by the `numprocs` option in the `supervisord.conf` file.

```
$ supervisord -n
```

Comment: Okay got it. Will update the answer soon. :)